# HTTP 405 error when accessing Keycloak admin UI

Tags: user-interface, keycloak, admin

Trying to use Keycloak Version 21.0.1 in docker behind Spring Cloud Gateway running in Kubernetes cluster. Started Keycloak with KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH environment variable with /keycloak and configured the same in Gateway so any call made to /keycloak is forwarded to Keycloak. Able to get token using /keycloak through Cloud gateway IP address in Postman but when trying to access Keycloak admin UI through browser, the login page can't load with error in Keycloak logs as below:

2023-08-25 18:10:50,822 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (executor-thread-2) Error response 405: jakarta.ws.rs.NotAllowedException: RESTEASY003650: No resource method found for GET, return 405 with Allow header.

The browser developer console displays net::ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method Not Allowed) when loading js and css files.

Tried to access the UI using the load balancer IP of Keycloak also, but still getting the same error.

But without this custom HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH and when starting and accessing Keycloak, there is no issue accessing admin UI using default path like /.

Any areas to look for fix??

Thanks in advance.